# Problem trying to attach GLFW window to WinAPI window

Tags: c++, winapi, glfw

I have a handle on standard window using WINAPI. Now I am trying to attach GLFW window to it. Below is the code I am trying to make work.

The code is taken from here: [LINK](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/commit/4e96e90f64c6ba18c0ae51949bcd67dfc112e76e)

```
LPCTSTR WindowName = "Untitled - Notepad";
HWND hwnd = FindWindow("Notepad", WindowName);

GLFWwindow* glfwWndNew = glfwCreateWindow (width, height, *title, NULL, NULL)

GLFWwindow* glfwWnd = glfwAttachWin32Window(hwnd, glfwWndNew);

GLint windowWidth, windowHeight;
glfwGetWindowSize(glfwWnd, &windowWidth, &windowHeight);
```

**Couple of questions:**

1. It seems that although the piece of code compiles and the function is correctly found in the code, i.e. I can jump to glfw3native.h file where the definition is, it still says: `identifier glfwAttachWin32Window is undefined`. The build fails with `error C3861: 'glfwAttachWin32Window': identifier not found` Not sure, what it wants exactly as I said it finds the declaration in the header file.
2. Any other ways to do the same thing? I mean, I was only able to find this implementation, which seems to be on the branch and never finished, but any other options? What I need exactly is:

   GLFWwindow* glfwWnd = glfwAttachWin32Window(hwnd, glfwWndNew);

There is this solution here as well: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488700/using-glfw-to-render-and-winapi-to-handle-messages) but I am not quite sure of how to use it in this context. As I don't need a new Win32 window, but rather to attach GLFW window to an existing one.

Here is the Output from building the glfw3.lib:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Checking Build System
2>------ Build started: Project: glfw, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>Building Custom Rule /glfw-3.3.5/src/CMakeLists.txt
2>context.c
2>init.c
2>input.c
2>monitor.c
2>vulkan.c
2>window.c
2>win32_init.c
2>win32_joystick.c
2>win32_monitor.c
2>win32_time.c
2>win32_thread.c
2>win32_window.c
2>wgl_context.c
2>egl_context.c
2>osmesa_context.c
2>Generating Code...
2>glfw.vcxproj -> glfw-3.3.5\src\Debug\glfw3.lib
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The failed program compilation looks like this:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: , Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>test.cpp
test.cpp(69,25): error C3861: 'glfwAttachWin32Window': identifier not found
1>Done building project "test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

In glfw3native.h as mentioned above in one of the links, the definition looks like this:

```
#if defined(GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_WIN32)
/*! @brief Returns the adapter device name of the specified monitor.
 *
 *  @return The UTF-8 encoded adapter device name (for example `\\.\DISPLAY1`)
 *  of the specified monitor, or `NULL` if an [error](@ref error_handling)
 *  occurred.
 *
 *  @errors Possible errors include @ref GLFW_NOT_INITIALIZED.
 *
 *  @thread_safety This function may be called from any thread.  Access is not
 *  synchronized.
 *
 *  @since Added in version 3.1.
 *
 *  @ingroup native
 */
GLFWAPI const char* glfwGetWin32Adapter(GLFWmonitor* monitor);

/*! @brief Returns the display device name of the specified monitor.
 *
 *  @return The UTF-8 encoded display device name (for example
 *  `\\.\DISPLAY1\Monitor0`) of the specified monitor, or `NULL` if an
 *  [error](@ref error_handling) occurred.
 *
 *  @errors Possible errors include @ref GLFW_NOT_INITIALIZED.
 *
 *  @thread_safety This function may be called from any thread.  Access is not
 *  synchronized.
 *
 *  @since Added in version 3.1.
 *
 *  @ingroup native
 */
GLFWAPI const char* glfwGetWin32Monitor(GLFWmonitor* monitor);

/*! @brief Returns the `HWND` of the specified window.
 *
 *  @return The `HWND` of the specified window, or `NULL` if an
 *  [error](@ref error_handling) occurred.
 *
 *  @errors Possible errors include @ref GLFW_NOT_INITIALIZED.
 *
 *  @remark The `HDC` associated with the window can be queried with the
 *  [GetDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdc)
 *  function.
 *  @code
 *  HDC dc = GetDC(glfwGetWin32Window(window));
 *  @endcode
 *  This DC is private and does not need to be released.
 *
 *  @thread_safety This function may be called from any thread.  Access is not
 *  synchronized.
 *
 *  @since Added in version 3.0.
 *
 *  @ingroup native
 */
GLFWAPI HWND glfwGetWin32Window(GLFWwindow* window);
/*! @brief Wraps an existing `HWND` in a new GLFW window object.
 *
 *  This function creates a GLFW window object and its associated OpenGL or
 *  OpenGL ES context for an existing `HWND`.  The `HWND` is not destroyed by
 *  GLFW.
 *
 *  @param[in] handle The `HWND` to attach to the window object.
 *  @param[in] share The window whose context to share resources with, or `NULL`
 *  to not share resources.
 *  @return The handle of the created window, or `NULL` if an
 *  [error](@ref error_handling) occurred.
 *
 *  @errors Possible errors include @ref GLFW_NOT_INITIALIZED, @ref
 *  GLFW_INVALID_ENUM, @ref GLFW_INVALID_VALUE, @ref GLFW_API_UNAVAILABLE, @ref
 *  GLFW_VERSION_UNAVAILABLE, @ref GLFW_FORMAT_UNAVAILABLE and @ref
 *  GLFW_PLATFORM_ERROR.
 *
 *  @thread_safety This function may be called from any thread.
 *
 *  @sa @ref window_creation
 *  @sa @ref glfwCreateWindow
 *
 *  @since Added in version 3.3.
 *
 *  @ingroup native
 */
GLFWAPI GLFWwindow* glfwAttachWin32Window(HWND handle, GLFWwindow* share);
#endif
```

Comment: Added the output from building the glfw3.lib and the error as well, I suppose it was the error code you were after..

Comment: The glfw3.lib is successful, the actual program output I have posted in the body as well. Will do it explicitly.

Comment: I am trying to see if anything can hit why the function is undefined.

Comment: Sure. Added the output. As I've mentioned, it jumps to the definition, which is GLFWAPI GLFWwindow* glfwAttachWin32Window(HWND handle, GLFWwindow* share); in glwf3native.h, but then still not able to compile it.
Added the .h file for completeness. It is in one of the links (the first one).

Comment: This question and `#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_WIN32` may be related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679985/glfw3-error-glfwgetwin32window-was-not-declared-in-this-scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679985/glfw3-error-glfwgetwin32window-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)

Comment: That helps. Must be something to do with #define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_WIN32. Haven't figured out what yet.

Comment: The answer for that question says you have to have `#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_WIN32` before including `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` and `#include <GLFW/glfw3native.h>`  and that the glfw3native include must be after glfw3

Comment: Fixed with what you have posted above. Thank you very much.

Comment: Which version has the `glfwAttachWin32Window`? I've downloaded the latest from the github repository, and tried the earlier ones, but none of them seem to have it...